# Add HTML tag inside parent using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add a child HTML tag using JS to a parent without an ID or class (so I need to target the parent level up).

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="parent">
  <lavel>
    <input type="radio">
  </label>
</div>
```

Here is what I need:

```
<div class="parent">
  <lavel>
    <input type="radio">
    <span class="child-span">content</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Any help? Thx.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: Show your attempt and let us know where you been stuck.

Comment: And where is your javascript test ?

Answer (score 2):

Access the children of the parent:

```js
const el = document.createElement('span')
el.classList.add('child-span')
el.innerText = 'Hello!'

document.querySelector('.parent').children[0].appendChild(el)
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label>
    <input type="radio">
  </label>
</div>
```

Or query the element directly:

```js
const el = document.createElement('span')
el.classList.add('child-span')
el.innerText = 'Hello!'

document.querySelector('.parent label').appendChild(el)
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label>
    <input type="radio">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of `children[0]` a more robust way would be to still lookup the node needed. It could still be done directly with the query selector if you pass `.parent label`. Still, that's only a consideration when implementing the solution - I think the code given here is a good illustration of how to do it, the details can vary between implementations.

Answer (score 0):

IF jQuery is allowed

```js
 $('.parent label').append('<span class="child-span">content</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <label>
    <input type="radio">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use document.getelementbyid to create a new div and then add what is required in that div.

```
Var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
                 //and give it some content 
                var newContent = document.createElement("");
                 //add the text node to the newly created div
                newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  
                //add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
   var currentDiv = document.getElementById(""); 
            document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
            }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` will not *create* a new div, it would look up one that exists.

Comment: This allows you to select the parent element and then add whatever attributes you want through javascript. Very efficient.